# What does it mean to find the stationary states of a free particle in a cubic well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Sorry if this is an elementary question but Im not sure what it physically means to find the stationary states of a free particle in a cubic well. If anybody has some insight i'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I guess an equivalently good question would be what does the word state mean in this context? What does it mean to be in a QM state?

Comment: A cubic well (third order polynomial potential in one dimension) wouldn't have any stationary wave functions, even though it may have some quasi-stationary ones (i.e. there would be an imaginary component of their energy eigenvalue which describes a decay rate). Do you mean a cubic box instead? For the cubic potential with decaying solutions many approximation methods have been described in the literature, e.g. "Decay Rates of Metastable States in Cubic Potential by Variational Perturbation Theory", H. Klenert, I. Mustapic.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're asking specifically about states in a cubic potential, or whether you're asking what a *stationary state* is and the potential doesn't matter.